# Additional partitioning with Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I'm having trouble creating an additional storage partition during installation. I have a 1TB hdd and I'm following the basic partitioning outline showed in this thread https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PartitioningSchemes . What I want is for the remaining free space to be allocated to a separate partition, so that it would look like an additional hdd when logged in. I am unsure on how to setup this partition eg. Primary or Logical, end or beginning of space? Lastly how can I specify the size of the Downloads folder located under home for the user? Any help or useful links would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a GPT partition table scheme, then all your partititons can be primary (up to 128 of them). If you have a MBR partition table scheme, you can have up to 4 primary partition, all other partitions must be logical and must be included in an extended partition. A folder size is usually 4kb. The total contents of a folder can be any size, but not exceeding the partition size where it resides.

Comment: @ipselute With a little more content, this fits as an answer